# Unidentified "Sigma Mount Compatible" Bike Computer

Tags: accessories, bike-computer, cadence

Just got this used bike computer, only knew it fits in a Sigma type "Twist Lock System" mounts.
No markings on the front or sides only a serial number stamped on the back.

Really hope someone can shed some *`backlight`* :)

[image: kcal] calories, kcal display

[image: temp] temperature readout (C / F), Min and Max memory

[image: cr2032 plate] just battery plate markings on the back...

### Settings mode

[image: set weight] set Kg / Lbs (default Kg starts at 65)

[image: total distance] preset Total Distance (2 bikes)

[image: service] service 'feature' (default: 600) range: 200-999, also settable for bike1 and bike2

### Electronic board

[image: mb] readable series "E30370-01"

[image]

All in all looks like a good piece of hardware, also seems to have some data connection with battery removed (`Vcc`, `Vdd`, `Vpp`) would be very interested if/how it's PC link-able.

*Edit:*
With data from sigmasport's service website, made a [makeshift product history](https://jsfiddle.net/ca25qs6c/embedded/result/), still it's not on the list...

Comment: not a clue what that model is, but Sigma is indeed a company that makes bike computers. I have one of their HRMs. Try looking at [www.sigmasport.com/en/produkte/fahrrad-computer](http://www.sigmasport.com/en/produkte/fahrrad-computer)

Comment: came here after being disappointed with sigmasport's website, no results on ebay and google serving crap...

Comment: Those are not data pins. Vcc and Vdd are only supply pins/testpads. I don’t know what Vpp is, usually it would be a peak-to-peak voltage for AC voltage but that obviously doesn’t make sense in this context. There is probably a debug connector for the microcontroller somewhere on the board, but you won’t be able to do anything with it.

Comment: You should email this to Sigma.  I'm sure they'll be interested to see what is quite possibly an unauthorized clone of their hardware.

Comment: The manufacturer appears to be "Multi Consumer Products AG" near Frankfurt. From a brief search I've found page references to bike computers made by them, and the odd product manual. Their website is offline since mid-2013 (Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130111153754/http://www.mcp-ag.net/). Items branded as "Bikemate" appear to have been distributed through Aldi outlets. I didn't yet find the model you have. Perhaps search for "bikemate computer" on Google Image Search? PS: didn't find glowing reviews :-)

Answer (score 1):

SIGMA make a connecting pod with USB connection to the PC. It takes the bike computer via twist lock. They have their own data suite for reading and archiving data from the bike computer. You should find it on their website.

Comment: Newer Sigma computers use a proprietary two-pin opening key for the battery compartment instead of the coin-slot. Though I don't know which year marked the switch.

Comment: The BC series - one of which this looks like - does still have the coin slot opening and doesn't have any PC connection.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an older generation Sigma Sport bike computer with that has its silk screened logos worn away. The two 7-segment displays and small alphanumeric display in the center are their trade mark and as you noticed, the mount is Sigma.

The second set of connections in the mount is for cadence sensor that is sold separately.

Over the years, Sigma has made lots of computers that have nearly same functionality and mount but different casings. This is not one of the latest models, I would guess early 2000s. And since this has second bike and cadence sensor support, I would guess a model closer to high end.